# How to implement social login in asp.net mvc 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I want to implement role based login using oauth with facebook, twitter, google etc. It will only be using oauth and will have a role system. Not the default template with the usual registration and login. Seems like dot net open auth will help withe initial stuff, but i can find no good example of using or extending it. Can someone explain how to use dotnet open auth from scratch and how to get extra info with it?

Comment: The documentation is pretty extensive (and linked from the AuthConfig.cs file! http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=252166)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Launch Visual Studio 2012
2. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 application using the Internet Template
3. Open the `~/App_Start/AuthConfig.cs` file
4. Uncomment the providers you want to use by putting your client key and secret for the corresponding provider

For more information about OAuth integration I invite you to head to the [`DotNetOpenAuth`](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) site, go through the [`documentation`](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/), download and play with the samples.

Comment: i know that MVC 4 comes with those in Internet Application Template. I need only the social login without the 'create an account' the usual way. And i also need to get more information from the sites like email, username ... etc

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov hey Darin if I want to open an empty project how do I implement a Facebook login/create/update/delete users ? Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Open the ~/App_Start/AuthConfig.cs file and Use [this](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/08/facebook-twitter-oauth-openid-login-with-aspnet-mvc-4-application.html)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;

namespace MVCTemplateProject
{
    public static class AuthConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterAuth()
        {

            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterMicrosoftClient(
               clientId: "code",
                clientSecret: "code");

            //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterTwitterClient(
            //    consumerKey: "",
            //    consumerSecret: "");

            //OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
            //    appId: "",
            //    appSecret: "");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterLinkedInClient("code", "code");
            OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();
        }
    }
}
```