# Oauth In Asp.net Webapi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, asp.net-web-api

I am learning how to use the asp.net webapi. I want to make an admin area where I can do admin stuff but also add,edit,delete stuff into my database.

I believe I need to make some regular asp.net mvc views and controllers for this. I of course want to secure these pages and only let authorized users in.

I would like to use Oauth. I know that mvc 4 now has build in support now for it but I am not sure which nuget package to download into my webapi project.

I am also unclear if you can register any oauth provider. I am looking at the asp.net mvc 4 internet soultion and I see like RegisterGoogle, RegisterFacebook yet I don't see an option for foursquare and I am not sure if I can add it myself or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an article that detailed a lot of this in May's issue of MSDN magazine titled [Social Authenitciation in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198238.aspx). I think this has what you are looking for, but there is also another similar stack overrflow question answered in [How to implement social login in asp.net mvc 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550286/how-to-implement-social-login-in-asp-net-mvc-4)